# Why I use new BitArray(byte[]), Can't get right bits

Tags: c#, bitarray

```
byte[] test = new byte[] {36, 146};

BitArray ba = new BitArray(test);

for(int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i++)
  Debug.Log(ba[i]);
```

I want get bits is :

```
False False True False False True False False True False False True False False True False
```

but return is:

```
False False True False False True False False False True False False True False False True
```

Why???

Comment: The bits are inserted in bit order, where least significant bit is bit 0 not bit 7. You don't notice this with 36 because in binary that is a palindrome.

Comment: `BitArray` stores bits as elements of array differently (first bit is least significant) than binary presentation which can easily lead to confusion. E.g. `1` is stored as `1000 0000` and `128` as `0000 0001`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try some different numbers, say `1` and `7` and let's have a different output:

```
 byte[] test = new byte[] {1, 7};

 BitArray ba = new BitArray(test);

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i++) {
   if (i > 0 && i % 8 == 0)
     sb.Append(' ');

   sb.Append(ba[i] ? '1' : '0');
 }

 Console.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Outcome:

```
 10000000 11100000
```

Can you see what's going on?

```
   1 -> 0b00000001 -> 10000000 -> True False False False False False False False
   7 -> 0b00000111 -> 11100000 -> True  True  True False False False False False
```

Let's return to initial values: `36, 146`

```
  36 -> 0b00100100 -> 00100100 -> False False  True False False  True False False
 146 -> 0b10010010 -> 01001001 -> False  True False False  True False False  True
```

When we put `1` in binary the 1st bit the **rightmost**: `00000001`, however when we represent the same `1` as a bit array we have the 1st bit **leftmost**: `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] == [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]`.

Unfortunately, `36` is a binary *palindrome* `00100100` it reads equaly from left to right and from right to left, which I think is the cause of the surprised behaviour (why first 8 bits are correct when last 8 are not).

Comment: Thank you! 00100100 is read equaly from left to right  and from right to left! HaHa